# SBSJsonParser XCode 6 Compiler warnings

Tags: sbjson

I have a small app I am testing in XCode6 and I get 2 compiler warnings for the SBSJsonParser.m file

Semantic Issue variable 'k' may be uninitialized when used here (in function scanRestOfDictionary)

c++;
        if (![self scanValue:&v]) {
            NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Object value expected for key: %@", k];
            [self addErrorWithCode:EPARSE description: string];
            return NO;
        }

and same again variable 'lo' may be uninitialized when used here (in function scanUnicodeChar)

```
        if (lo < 0xdc00 || lo >= 0xdfff) {
            [self addErrorWithCode:EUNICODE description:@"Invalid low surrogate char"];
            return NO;
        }
```

anyone with any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Erm, which version of SBJson are you using? Version 2.3.x? Version 3 and above doesn't have the code you're referring to in a file with that name. Version 4 and above doesn't have that *class*.

If you're still using a SBJson version prior to version 3.0, I'd suggest you just should use NSJSONSerialisation instead. If you insist on using SBJson I suggest you upgrade to either version 3 or 4 series. (Depending on your needs.)

(Disclaimer: I am the author of SBJson.)